# Lodash difference of two arrays that matches only one key

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an array's like this

```
var old = [ { id: 1, name: 'Super edit' },
  { id: 2, name: 'new item' },
  { id: 19, name: 'new item' } ]

var new = [ { id: 1, name: 'Super edit' },{ id: 2, name: 'new item' }]
```

I would like to get the difference of the above two that don't matches the key `id`.

Expected result:

```
[{ id: 19, name: 'new item' }]
```

What I've tried is

`_.differenceWith(old,new,_.isEqual)` but its checks both `id` and `name`
 how can i get array's that matches only  the key `id`

Comment: Is using lodash *required*?

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `_.differenceBy()` with the `id` as the iteratee shorthand.

**Notes:** `new` is a [reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Reserved_keywords_as_of_ECMAScript_2015) in javascript, and can't be used for variable names.

```js
const oldArr = [{ id: 1, name: 'Super edit' },{ id: 2, name: 'new item' },{ id: 19, name: 'new item' }]

const newArr = [ { id: 1, name: 'Super edit' },{ id: 2, name: 'new item' }]

const result = _.differenceBy(oldArr, newArr, 'id')

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have options as usual with _.lodash.

If you want to **mutate** the array then use [_.pullAllBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#pullAllBy)

If you do not want to mutate the array use [_.differenceBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#differenceBy)

```js
var old = [{ id: 1, name: 'Super edit' }, { id: 2, name: 'new item' }, { id: 19, name: 'new item' } ]
var current = [{ id: 1, name: 'Super edit' }, { id: 2, name: 'new item' }]

console.log(_.differenceBy(old, current,'id'))  // this will NOT mutate
console.log(old, current)  // Notice no changes to any of the arrays

console.log(_.pullAllBy(old, current,'id'))    // this will
console.log(old, current)  // Notice old array is now changed
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```